# Issue with C++ Serial Communication on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, arduino, serial-port

I'm trying to communicate with an Arduino using C++ on windows.

The Arduino is waiting for a number and will light up an amount of LEDs specified by the received number. I can successfully open a port and send data to the Arduino, however there is some strange behavior.

When I use the built-in serial console in the Arduino IDE and send, for example, "8" the Arduino reacts correctly. (The data sent is `38 0A` according to a serial sniffer).

When I run my C++ code, the data sent is also `38 0A` however the Arduino does not react to it.

My PC side C++ code:

```cpp
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>


bool write(void* data, int len)
{
    HANDLE hPort;
    hPort = CreateFile("\\\\.\\COM4", GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

    DCB dcb = { 0 };
    dcb.DCBlength = sizeof(dcb);

    DWORD byteswritten;

    if (!GetCommState(hPort, &dcb)) return false;

    dcb.BaudRate = CBR_115200;
    dcb.ByteSize = 8;
    dcb.Parity = NOPARITY;
    dcb.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;

    if (!SetCommState(hPort, &dcb)) return false;

    bool retVal = WriteFile(hPort, data, len, &byteswritten, NULL);
    CloseHandle(hPort);
    return retVal;
}

int main() 
{
    char lpBuffer[] = "8\n";
    if (write(lpBuffer, strlen(lpBuffer))) {
        std::cout << "Success" << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Error" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And here is the Arduino code although I assume the problem will be on the PC side...

```cpp
#define BAUD 115200

int pins[] = {A5, A4, A3, 2, 4, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13};
int count = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(BAUD);
  
  for(int pin : pins) {
    pinMode(pin, OUTPUT);
  }
}

void updateLeds(int cnt) {
  if(cnt > sizeof(pins)) cnt = sizeof(pins);

  for(int pin : pins) {
    digitalWrite(pin, LOW);
  }

  for(int i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
    digitalWrite(pins[i], HIGH);
  }
}

void loop() {
  if(Serial.available() > 0) {      
    Serial.println("[RECV]");
    count = Serial.parseInt();
    Serial.read();
  }
  updateLeds(count);

  delay(50);
}
```

Comment: You aren't setting anywhere near all of the important members of `DCB`, which means that you are at the mercy of the configuration setup by the last program to use the serial port.

Comment: When you say "the data sent is also 38 0A" does this mean you have seen the data come out the serial port?  Or just that is what is in the buffer you passed to `WriteFile`?  If your flowcontrol and handshaking settings are wrong, the PC will never actually transmit the data.

Comment: @BenVoigt I have seen the data through a serial sniffer. It is `38 0A` and nothing more...

Comment: Try to enable DTR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Julian mentioned in the comments, enabling DTR did the trick.

```cpp
...
dcb.fDtrControl = DTR_CONTROL_HANDSHAKE;
...
```